# Perform SUM operation in XSLT

Tags: xslt

In the below input we have to check the supplier code if it is match to any of the node supplier code then we have to perform sum operation on Quantity.otherwise directly map the quantity.

input:

```
<Move-Afile>
  <Afile>
    <Item>
    <suppliercode>1</suppliercode>
      <PackNumber>1234</PackNumber>
      <Quantity>12</Quantity>
    </Item>
    <Item>
    <suppliercode>2</suppliercode>
      <PackNumber>567</PackNumber>
      <Quantity>3</Quantity>
    </Item>
    <Item>
    <suppliercode>1</suppliercode>
      <PackNumber>567</PackNumber>
      <Quantity>8</Quantity>
    </Item>
    <Item>
    <suppliercode>3</suppliercode>
      <PackNumber>126</PackNumber>
      <Quantity>11</Quantity>
    </Item>
    <Item>
    <suppliercode>4</suppliercode>
      <PackNumber>876</PackNumber>
      <Quantity>32</Quantity>
    </Item>
  </Afile>
</Move-Afile>
```

If supplier code is equal then perform sum operation on Quantity,otherwise directly map the Quantity.

output:

```
<A>
  <target>
    <Item>
    <suppliercode>1</suppliercode>
      <PackNumber>1234</PackNumber>
      <Quantity>20</Quantity>
    </Item>
    <Item>
    <suppliercode>2</suppliercode>
      <PackNumber>567</PackNumber>
      <Quantity>3</Quantity>
    </Item>
    <Item>
    <suppliercode>1</suppliercode>
      <PackNumber>567</PackNumber>
      <Quantity>20</Quantity>
    </Item>
    <Item>
    <suppliercode>3</suppliercode>
      <PackNumber>126</PackNumber>
      <Quantity>11</Quantity>
    </Item>
    <Item>
    <suppliercode>4</suppliercode>
      <PackNumber>876</PackNumber>
      <Quantity>32</Quantity>
    </Item>
  </target>
</A>
```

i need the sum logic in a separate temporary variable like below.

```
<varaible name=tempvar>
<xsl:choose>
<xsl:when suppliercode=suppliercode>

<xsl:value-of select=sum(quntity)/>

<xsl:when>

<xsl:otherwise>

<xsl:value-of select=quntity/>

</xsl:otherwise>

</xsl:choose>

</variable>
```

Comment: Sorry, but the fact that you say "i need the sum logic in a separate temporary variable like below", doesn't mean at all that doing this is needed. You need either to provide a realistic example that convinces the reader that this is necessary, or otherwise just use the solutions that have been proposed. Two solutions have been given, that produce exactly the wanted output, without capturing the sum in an intermediary variable. This proves that such capturing is unnecessary -- unless you convince us to the opposite.

Comment: in my requirement i am using a for loop.somewhere i want to use this logic,thats why i  need this in seperate variable or please provide the solution with for each.

Answer (score 0):

This stylesheet does what you require. It copies all elements from `Item` downwards, and has a special template to change the value of `Quantity` by adding the values of all `Quantity` elements from `Item` elements that have the same value of `suppliercode`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <A>
      <target>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Move-Afile/Afile/Item"/>
      </target>
    </A>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Quantity">
    <xsl:variable name="supplier-code" select="parent::Item/suppliercode"/>
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:value-of select="sum(ancestor::Afile/Item[suppliercode = $supplier-code]/Quantity)"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**output**

```
<A>
   <target>
      <Item>
         <suppliercode>1</suppliercode>
         <PackNumber>1234</PackNumber>
         <Quantity>20</Quantity>
      </Item>
      <Item>
         <suppliercode>2</suppliercode>
         <PackNumber>567</PackNumber>
         <Quantity>3</Quantity>
      </Item>
      <Item>
         <suppliercode>1</suppliercode>
         <PackNumber>567</PackNumber>
         <Quantity>20</Quantity>
      </Item>
      <Item>
         <suppliercode>3</suppliercode>
         <PackNumber>126</PackNumber>
         <Quantity>11</Quantity>
      </Item>
      <Item>
         <suppliercode>4</suppliercode>
         <PackNumber>876</PackNumber>
         <Quantity>32</Quantity>
      </Item>
   </target>
</A>
```

---

**Update**
To put the total into a variable before using it, you can replace the last template with this

```
  <xsl:template match="Quantity">
    <xsl:variable name="supplier-code" select="parent::Item/suppliercode"/>
    <xsl:variable name="total" select="sum(ancestor::Afile/Item[suppliercode = $supplier-code]/Quantity)"/>
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:value-of select="$total"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
```

which sets the value of `$total` to the sum of the quantities with the same suppplier code.

Comment: <varaible name=tempvar> <xsl:choose> <xsl:when suppliercode=suppliercode> <xsl:value-of select=sum(quntity)/> <xsl:when> <xsl:otherwise> <xsl:value-of select=quntity/> </xsl:otherwise> </xsl:choose> </variable>

Comment: i need the logic of sum in a separate variable.can we do that like above comment

Comment: I have added to my answer to do what you ask.

Answer (score 0):

**This short and efficient (using a key) transformation:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:key name="kQuantityBySupplier" match="Quantity" use="../suppliercode"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
  <A>
    <target>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*/node()"/>
    </target>
  </A>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="Quantity/text()">
  <xsl:value-of select="sum(key('kQuantityBySupplier', ../../suppliercode))"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<Move-Afile>
  <Afile>
    <Item>
    <suppliercode>1</suppliercode>
      <PackNumber>1234</PackNumber>
      <Quantity>12</Quantity>
    </Item>
    <Item>
    <suppliercode>2</suppliercode>
      <PackNumber>567</PackNumber>
      <Quantity>3</Quantity>
    </Item>
    <Item>
    <suppliercode>1</suppliercode>
      <PackNumber>567</PackNumber>
      <Quantity>8</Quantity>
    </Item>
    <Item>
    <suppliercode>3</suppliercode>
      <PackNumber>126</PackNumber>
      <Quantity>11</Quantity>
    </Item>
    <Item>
    <suppliercode>4</suppliercode>
      <PackNumber>876</PackNumber>
      <Quantity>32</Quantity>
    </Item>
  </Afile>
</Move-Afile>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<A>
   <target>
      <Item>
         <suppliercode>1</suppliercode>
         <PackNumber>1234</PackNumber>
         <Quantity>20</Quantity>
      </Item>
      <Item>
         <suppliercode>2</suppliercode>
         <PackNumber>567</PackNumber>
         <Quantity>3</Quantity>
      </Item>
      <Item>
         <suppliercode>1</suppliercode>
         <PackNumber>567</PackNumber>
         <Quantity>20</Quantity>
      </Item>
      <Item>
         <suppliercode>3</suppliercode>
         <PackNumber>126</PackNumber>
         <Quantity>11</Quantity>
      </Item>
      <Item>
         <suppliercode>4</suppliercode>
         <PackNumber>876</PackNumber>
         <Quantity>32</Quantity>
      </Item>
   </target>
</A>
```

**Do note**:

The time complexity of this transformation is linear (O(N)). This can be orders of magnitude more efficient than repeatedly scanning all elements to find the ones having a given `suppliercode` -- which has quadratical (O(N^2)) time complexity.

---

**Update**:

The OP has specified a new requirement, that the sum or the single quantity be captured in a variable:

**Just modify this**:

```
 <xsl:template match="Quantity/text()">
  <xsl:value-of select="sum(key('kQuantityBySupplier', ../../suppliercode))"/>
 </xsl:template>
```

**into this**:

```
 <xsl:template match="Quantity/text()">
  <xsl:variable name="vSum" select="sum(key('kQuantityBySupplier', ../../suppliercode))"/>
  <xsl:value-of select="$vSum"/>
 </xsl:template>
```

Comment: <varaible name=tempvar>
<xsl:choose>
<xsl:when suppliercode=suppliercode>

<xsl:value-of select=sum(quntity)/>

<xsl:when>

<xsl:otherwise>

<xsl:value-of select=quntity/>

</xsl:otherwise>

</xsl:choose>

</variable>

Comment: i need the logic of sum in a separate variable.can we do that like above comment.

Comment: @sum, Yes, the sum can be captured in a variable, however no such requirement is present in the question and it is not clear if such capturing is needed at all. This question, in its present form, is completely answered. Please, either edit the question, or, preferably, ask a new question with the new requirement.

Comment: @sum, Please, see the update to this answer -- this implements your latest requirement.