# Perform an XSLT Logic

Tags: xslt

input:

```
<Move-Afile>
  <Afile>
    <Item>
    <suppliercode>1</suppliercode>
      <PackNumber>1234</PackNumber>
      <Item85>
      <Quantity>12</Quantity>
      </Item85>
    </Item>
    <Item>
    <suppliercode>2</suppliercode>
      <PackNumber>567</PackNumber>
      <Item85>
      <Quantity>3</Quantity>
      </Item85>
    </Item>
    <Item>
    <suppliercode>1</suppliercode>
      <PackNumber>567</PackNumber>
      <Item85>
      <Quantity>8</Quantity>
        </Item85>
    </Item>
    <Item>
    <suppliercode>3</suppliercode>
      <PackNumber>126</PackNumber>
       <Item85>
      <Quantity>11</Quantity>
       </Item85>
    </Item>
    <Item>
    <suppliercode>4</suppliercode>
      <PackNumber>876</PackNumber>
       <Item85>
      <Quantity>32</Quantity>
       </Item85>
    </Item>
  </Afile>
</Move-Afile>
```

xslt:

i need the solution like the xsl should contain for-each structure like below.

If supplier codes are equal then we have to sum the quantity values of those nodes,otherwise directly map the quantity value.

```
<xsl:for-each select="/Move-Afile/Afile/Item">

  <xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test="suppliercode=suppliercode>

  <xsl:value-of select=sum(Quantity)"/><!-- sum of quantity where nodes have equal supplier  code-->
  </xsl:when>

  <xsl:otherwise>

  <xsl:value-of select="Quantity"/><!-- map directly the quantity value-->

  </xsl:otherwise>

  </xsl:choose>

  </xsl:for-each>
```

output:

```
<A>
   <target>
      <Item>

         <Quantity>20</Quantity>
      </Item>
      <Item>

         <Quantity>3</Quantity>
      </Item>
      <Item>

         <Quantity>20</Quantity>
      </Item>
      <Item>

         <Quantity>11</Quantity>
      </Item>
      <Item>

         <Quantity>32</Quantity>
      </Item>
   </target>
</A>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Perform SUM operation in XSLT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16636800/perform-sum-operation-in-xslt)

Comment: What was wrong with the answers you got to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16636800)?

Comment: nothing wrong.Just i need to use the logic inside the foreach.i have used the  below xpath.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really need an **xsl:choose** here, just a single sum statement to sum all **Quantity** elements for **Item** elements with the same **suppliercode** (which include the current node you are on).

```
<xsl:value-of select="sum(//Item[suppliercode = current()/suppliercode]/Item85/Quantity)"/>
```

However, it would be more efficient to make use of a key to look for matching **Item** elements:

```
<xsl:key name="Item" match="Item" use="suppliercode" />
```

Then the sum statement is simplified to this

```
<xsl:value-of select="sum(key('Item', suppliercode)/Item85/Quantity)"/>
```

You might also like to consider using the XSLT identity transform in building your output XML, as this would be more flexible. You would probably only need a template matching the **Quantity** element in this case

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:key name="Item" match="Item" use="suppliercode" />

   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="Quantity">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:value-of select="sum(key('Item', ../../suppliercode)/Item85/Quantity)"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to your XML, the following is output

```
<Move-Afile>
    <Afile>
        <Item>
            <suppliercode>1</suppliercode>
            <PackNumber>1234</PackNumber>
            <Item85>
                <Quantity>20</Quantity>
            </Item85>
        </Item>
        <Item>
            <suppliercode>2</suppliercode>
            <PackNumber>567</PackNumber>
            <Item85>
                <Quantity>3</Quantity>
            </Item85>
        </Item>
        <Item>
            <suppliercode>1</suppliercode>
            <PackNumber>567</PackNumber>
            <Item85>
                <Quantity>20</Quantity>
            </Item85>
        </Item>
        <Item>
            <suppliercode>3</suppliercode>
            <PackNumber>126</PackNumber>
            <Item85>
                <Quantity>11</Quantity>
            </Item85>
        </Item>
        <Item>
            <suppliercode>4</suppliercode>
            <PackNumber>876</PackNumber>
            <Item85>
                <Quantity>32</Quantity>
            </Item85>
        </Item>
    </Afile>
</Move-Afile>
```

If you do want to change or remove other elements, just add separate templates for each case accordingly.

Comment: inside the foreach <xsl:for-each select="/Move-Afile/Afile/Item"> please correct this xpath <xsl:value-of select="sum(//Item[suppliercode = current()/../../suppliercode]/Item85/Quantity)"/>  it is giving value 0(zero).

Comment: I've made a correction to my answer. One thing to mention is that in your XML them Quantity is a child of the Item85 element within the Item element, and not a child of Item directly.